# Is Provocation necessarily deliberate?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Does provocation always imply that the provoker intender to provoke?

Is there such a thing as "accidental provocation"?

Is the 'deliberate' in "deliberate provocation" a redundant word?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In many cases, provocation is intentional. However, it could be used more loosely to describe a cause-effect relationship. For example, "He wandered in between the mother bear and her cubs, provoking an attack." Here, the provocation isn't intentional, but the action directly *provokes* the response.

The phrases "deliberate" or "accidental provocation" sound a little unusual to me, but they could be used to add emphasis to whether one intended to provoke or not. Usually it'll be clear from context, but it could be added to reinforce an idea.
"You got what you deserved, deliberately provoking the bear like that."

Comment: It took me a bit of thinking to come up with a word that Provoke is opposed to. Since provoke literally means "call forth a response" most of it's antonyms have a sense of "call for inaction" or "call for non-aggression". However the words it's actually opposed to are "wanton" and "gratuitous" since both mean "uncalled for action". They represent actions that are spontaneous, or at least are without immediate cause. This contrast helps to solidify that the key identifying factor of provoke is not intention, but causation.

Answer (score 3):

[dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/provoke)'s page on **provoke** makes absolutely no mention of intention. In fact it has examples of contemporary usage both of where intention exists:

> "When you were setting out to do this, did you have an idea of what kind of conversation you wanted to provoke from this project?"

and where it doesn't exist:

> "A senior military officer familiar with the photos told me that they would likely provoke a storm of outrage if released."

Hence I see no implication of intention within the word *provocation*.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary definitions tend towards provocation being deliberate but also recognize the possibility that it is not. For example, the decision to introduce a poll tax in the United Kingdom was not intended to stimulate adverse reaction but, as it turned out, provoked strong protest; it was a strong but not deliberate provocation. She spat in his face; it was a deliberate (rather than accidental) provocation. The word deliberate is therefore sometimes redundant, sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily provoke an animal to attack you through behaviour in the wild, while being completely oblivious to this consequence of your actions; simply for a lack of understanding of how animals perceive events and threats.

I do think that provocation of actions is not necessarily an intentional action. Factor in misunderstandings and language barriers ("YOU CALLED MY MOTHER WHAT?!") and you have a rich ground of accidents.